# Yaa Devii Sarva-Bhutessu Nidraa-Ruupenna Samsthitaa

Tags: atma, mind, consciousness

Thoughts are continuously created by us in *Manomay kosa* at Awaking state(state of consciousness). There are no thoughts while sleeping.

- What does it mean? Then who goes for sleep?
- Is our Body (Pancha Jyanendriya and Pancha Karmendriya) goes for sleep? Or
- Is our Mind and Brain(Man and Buddhi) goes for sleep? Or
- Is our Soul (JeevAtma) goes for sleep?

There are some possibilities :

- If Body (Pancha Jyanendriya and Pancha Karmendriya)  goes for sleep then, our Mind and Brain will awake us.
- If Mind and Brain(Mana and Buddhi) goes for sleep then, our(JivAtma) soul will awake us.
- If Soul (JivAtma)  goes for sleep then, everyone should have a same kind of sleep and its result. Then,
- (1) **Who goes for sleeping?**

But Sleeping differs from a person to person. Like: one gets sleep quickly,another takes an hours and hours to gets sleep.One wakes up early and another wakes up very late.

- (2) **On which sleeping is depended?**

> या देवी सर्वभुतेषु निद्रारूपेण संस्थिता ।
>
> नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमस्तस्यै नमो नमः ॥९॥
>
> Yaa Devii Sarva-Bhutessu Nidraa-Ruupenna Samsthitaa |
>
> Namas-Tasyai Namas-Tasyai Namas-Tasyai Namo Namah ||9||
>
> 9.1: To that Devi Who in All Beings is Abiding in the Form of Sleep,
>
> 9.2: Salutations to Her, Salutations to Her, Salutations to Her, Salutations again and again.

These verses says that Goddess Durga itself is in a form of nidra.

- (3) **What does it means?**

Everyone knows when we wake from sleep, it results in to Fresh and Fully charged body. Then

- (4) **Where does our body gets charged during sleep?**

[Reference for shloka](http://www.greenmesg.org/mantras_slokas/devi_durga-ya_devi_sarvabhutesu.php)

Comment: The body simply rests. It is the mind that sleeps. The mind returns back to its source in Deep sleep. That is why deep sleep is so refreshing. The mind gets completely rested in itself and thus when mind is fresh then body gets automatically fresh. That's why one feels so refreshed after sleep. The force of our karmas brings us back to the world, that is, the force of karma wakes one from deep sleep. That is why one cannot sleep forever. But then why are we not aware of this beautiful experience? Is there something beyond this? Is there something that is beyond sleep?

Comment: One must seek that which experiences all three states - deep sleep, dreaming, and wake consciousness. There is something that is beyond all. That is called the Final state (Turiya). This state of consciousness is beyond description, it is God Himself, it is Shivam, it is super-consciousness! When one is situated in this state of awareness always, then there is no need to sleep, the body, mind, ego everything is automatically fresh! That is what it means IMHO that Goddess Durga is abiding in all beings as a form of sleep. The sleep referred is Brahman or the Turiya state. All the best !

Comment: Have you read the book "Talks with Sri Ramana Maharshi" ? The whole book deals on this topic alone (The Self)

Comment: Not yet.Thanks you for your reference suggetion. I found a pdf of "Talks with Sri Ramana Maharshi" http://selfdefinition.org/ramana/Talks-with-Sri-Ramana-Maharshi--complete.pdf  Is this are you talking about?

Comment: Yes, thats the one. I have a hard copy of it and read it everyday. Its a eye opener.

Answer (score 4):

There is one world [Tatva](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tatvas#J.C3.B1.C4.81nendriya_-_5) (base) please remember it. when person have basic knowledge of anything its called Tatva Gyan (Elementary knowledge). Which is become the principal knowledge. Like in science whatever you see are made from pure or compound of Elements; Elements are made of Particles Electron, Neutron and proton; hence whatever you see are made from Electron, proton and Neutron. (refer: periodic chart). Similarly for the Human they are do all karma. All Karma are done by three things; Mind, Body and Speech. Body do acts(karma) by 5 Gyanendriyas (organs of knowledge) and 5 Karmendriyas(organs of senses).

There is require to understand mind, beyond being mind. Mind have five states. These are 5 states of consciousness in human forms.

```
Jagruti - Waking
Swapna - Dreaming
Sushupti - Deep Sleep (slumber)
Turiya - Underlying state in all the above states
Unmani or Turyateeta - State of enlightened beings where the cosmos is experienced as oneness.
```

So when mind is working its jagruti, when we are sleeping their are two possibilities, one either deep sleep when we have no thoughts, that give rest to mind like body have rest without it working, Turiya is stage when Consciousness of mind is become more higher. Dhyan (Meditation) is stage when the mind is in jagruti(alive, awaken) but which is not thinking. Like we awaken but in rest our body is not making movement, the Consciousness is possible, when mind is awaken but its not thinking on anything which give great rest to the mind.

(1) Who goes for sleeping?
As per above answer you understand that sleeping is one of the five stage of consciousness of mind. sleeping is our mind is not working and no thoughts, dream is different stage of mind. No thoughts in mind is the deep sleep stage of the consciousness, and we feel rest of mind on second day.

(2) On which sleeping is depended?
Mind; It is said *Man hi karta Man hi Bhokta*, means Everything is done by mind, and Mind what feel. Like science whatever we see, smell, taste are determined by mind, mind is what make you feel, same way in Spirituality too, Mind is what feel each and everything. All Sences organs are different but the karma of them is feel by mind. so whatever you see, feel, taste, hear, speak is what the mind is doing.

(3) What does it means?
God has made us and given lots grace, if there was no sleeping, people could never rest in their life. All things appear is Maya(illusion). So by giving Nindra(sleep) we thanks to divine. Like we can thanks for water, rain, air, Human body. We thanks to divine and feel grace, that they give it to us. If you have bulb in your house and you think about the Edison, and think if there was not invented you immediate feel grace (thankfulness) to him, like we thanks for giving Nindra(sleeping) so we can feel rest of mind and freshness.

(4) Where does our body gets charged during sleep?
The Mind, If we run for 1 km or work for whole day we feel so much tired, and we feel to give rest to the body right, same way sleep is the consciousness of mind which give us the Rest. Meditation is the process which learn that in awaken (Jagruti) stage, we have to give rest to our mind, by not thinking on miscellaneous things. This is possible by the Meditation. The practice of which make you capable to avoid unnecessary thinking possible, and to give rest to mind by not thinking on anything.

The senses and Body can be rest even we are not sleeping, just sit in rest that's it. Jivatma is always witness of everything. and All what we acts are only mind, Hence all Karmendriyas(organs of action) and Gyanendriyas(organs of sense) are ultimately feel by mind.