# What is the function of brain according to Hinduism?

Tags: consciousness, mind, body

I want to know what the function of brain is.

I'm talking about the physical organ brain not the mind.

What do the sacred texts say about the brain?

Comment: What do you mean by "Brain"? Gross one or Subtle one? Subtle one is called mind.

Comment: [MIND--ITS MYSTERIES AND CONTROL](http://www.dlshq.org/download/mind.htm) is a good book by Swami Sivananda.

Comment: There are [many questions](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/search?q=mind) asked already on Mind, consciousness. Just have a look at them.

Comment: the 'brain' - not to be confused with the mind - is part of the annamayakosa, the physical body. See - http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6758/where-does-a-soul-attached-to-the-body/6787#6787

Comment: Alternate nostril breathing. Check your nostrils. You know, when the left nostril is active then the right brain is active. And vice-versa. The right brain is music. The left brain is logic. So those who have the right nostril active would understand me better. If both are active you are in meditation. However if only the right nostril is active, no meditation happens. Your state changes every time you open and close your eyes. Read a little more here: http://www.artofliving.org/meditation/meditation-for-you/tips-to-improve-focus

Comment: @AmitSaxena Thank you. Can you please provide more information with sources if possible?

Comment: @Wally: I would recommend that you look into neuro-research done on Yoga which originates in Hinduism. Hindu texts talk about the mind more than the brain because brain is like the antenna through which the signals go and the response comes in the mind, the TV. In any case, here is a video which talks about Kriya Yoga (as is mentioned in Patanjali Yoga Sutras) and its effects on the brain: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F4S_4jX0ERA

Comment: @AmitSaxena "Numerous independent studies", "Psychiatrists from Indian ..", "Published research from "Sweden". Sounds like SnakeOil. In the end I found no mention of those so called "scientific" sources.

Comment: @AmitSaxena I searched scientific journals and was unable to find those "studies". Also, I think I already have an idea of what science says. I want to know what Hinduism says about Brain.

Comment: @Wally: You should look for peer-reviewed articles like this: http://www.ijoy.org.in/article.asp?issn=0973-6131;year=2016;volume=9;issue=1;spage=12;epage=19;aulast=Singh

It will take a lot of work but you might find what you are looking for.

Also, I would recommend that you read the Patanjali Yoga Sutras. They talk about various modulations of the mind. You may get some indirect hints on the behaviour of the brain from that.