# Do the Devas and Pitrs like eating meat?

Tags: gods, animals, yajna, sacrifice, pitru

The body of animals killed in Yajnas and Sraddhas go to the world of the Devas as well as the world of Pitrs. The Devas and Pitrs eat the flesh of the animals killed in the yajnas offered by humans.

My question is, do the Devas and Pitrs like eating meat or enjoy the taste of flesh? Is there any thing in Hindu scripture that mentions this?

Like for example, in the Mahabharata, Bhishma says that the flesh of deer is very tasty.

Comment: they do not eat corporeal flesh as they have no Annamayakosha sheath (the sanskrit annamaya refers to the alimentary canal in a human where food passes through). See here - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6758/where-does-a-soul-attach-to-the-body/6787#6787.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That the Pitris love eating meat is clear from the following Manu Smriti verses. They remain heavily satisfied specially when they are offered different kinds of meat.

> 3.267. The ancestors of men are satisfied for one month with sesamum grains, rice, barley, masha beans, water, roots, and fruits, which
>   have been given according to the prescribed rule,
>
> 3.268. Two months with fish, three months with the meat of gazelles, four with mutton, and five indeed with the flesh of birds,
>
> 3.269. Six months with the flesh of goats, seven with that of spotted deer, eight with that of the black antelope, but nine with that of the
>   (deer called) Ruru,
>
> 3.270. Ten months they are satisfied with the meat of boars and buffaloes, but eleven months indeed with that of hares and tortoises,
>
> 3.271. One year with cow-milk and milk-rice; from the flesh of a long-eared white he-goat their satisfaction endures twelve years.
>
> 3.272. The (vegetable called) Kalasaka, (the fish called) Mahasalka, the flesh of a rhinoceros and that of a red goat, and all kinds of
>   food eaten by hermits in the forest serve for an endless time

For the Gods, AFAIK, the Smritis do not (explicitly) say that they are very fond of eating meat. The Vyasa Smriti's Chapter 1, for example, has the following verse:

> **Milk, wine, honey, and clarified butter are the articles which the gods are fond of**. He should constantly study the Vedas except on the
>   interdicted days. On such days their other collateral subjects should
>   be' studied with the preceptor's permission. (38)

But I have a relevant verse from another scripture which I might add later.

Comment: The Devas sure love partying.

Comment: @Ikshvaku Devas were not that great!

Comment: Wine ? Except "Bhaang" being linked to the description of Lord Shiva, I have never heard of any deva having wine...

Comment: Devas are actually fond of wine (sura) .. that's why they are called Sura whereas demons, who don't like wine, are called Asuras. Sura or Varuni originally came out of the Samudra Manthan and then the gods accepted it gladly. Later due to some curses Sura or Varuni became impure and from then on there is prohibition on it's consumption.@PeDro