# Does a Jeevatman have any gender?

Tags: belief, atma, death, jiva, body

As discussed in this question - [Does a soul have any gender?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23699/does-a-soul-have-any-gender)
:

> No. All souls that enter the human body are not male because **the soul (or the Self) doesn't have any gender.**

However, most people confuse between a Jīvā (जीव) and Ātmān (आत्मन्), generally translating both of them as Souls.
In any case, there's a huge difference between an Ātmān & Jīvātmān ( जीवात्मन् ). This has been explained clearly in [this Answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6689/what-is-difference-between-aatma-jeevatma-and-paramatma/10619#10619):

> Ātmān simply means one's true Self. Ātmān which is quality-less and attribute-less when gets combined with prakruti, forms different kinds of senses (both subtle and gross) and gets different material natures. This combination of Ātmān and qualities arising from prakruti is called as Jīvātmān.

Now, when a person dies, they're judged for their *Karmas* and assigned appropriate Hell or Heaven or other rewards/punishments as per their karmic deeds.
 And the rewards or punishments are [expereinced by the Subtle body - *sūkṣmaśarīra*.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/33670/how-is-punishment-and-enjoyment-possible-in-hell-and-heaven-without-body/33673#33673)

> 22-23. According to their good or bad works, the Jîvas acquire the higher happy body and enjoy various pleasures in the Heavens, or they take up very painful vicious bodies and suffer various pains in hell.

---

**So the question(s):**

1. Since the rewards or punishments are to be experienced by the sūkṣmaśarīra, and at several instances, the punishments are given on a gender basis. For Example, [the punishments involving adultery](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10289/what-is-the-punishment-for-consensual-sex-in-hinduism), which involve punishments that do require a particular gender body to be carried out.
   **So does the scriptures explicitly say that the Subtle body (*sūkṣmaśarīra*) that is provided after birth (in hell or heaven) is Gendered?**
2. A Jīvā is also said to have imprints of all of its previous birth *saṃskāras* and other "*karmic*" debts. And thus building upon the above argument in the first question.
    **So, Does a Jīvātmān have any gender or is it genderless like an individual's *Ātmān*?**

Comment: I could not find any scripture references,but I saw this blog; https://yogaforums.com/t/an-overview-of-vedanta-part-1/9497/5

Comment: Jiva have gender in tattvavada propounded by Sri Madhvacharya I.e. soul have gender it's not Iin sushma/aniruddha or linga dheha as each soul is different and separate from brahman enjoy bliss or sorrow in moksha or andhantamas accordingly

Comment: Then this question a Male becoming female in next life how?there gender will be Male but born as female as per last minute thought when thinks about wife or lady at the time of death he will be born female and subsequently birth will be male but basic gender is intrinsic to the soul not to any dheha