# What are the 14 layers of the mind

Tags: vedas, vedanta, mind, consciousness

I had read somewhere that in the vedas the awareness can be divided into four categories, i.e chitta (consciousness/conscience), manas (heart/want/desire), aham (ego) and buddhi (intelligence).
Each of these categories can be further divided down and there are all total of 14 sub-categoris.
Can anyone tell me the name of all the sub-categories?

Comment: There are 17 divisions of the subtle body. Do you know if that is related to what you asked? Because manas (mind) is also one division of the subtle body.

Comment: see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6758/where-does-a-soul-attach-to-the-body/6787#6787

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does a Soul attach to the Body?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6758/where-does-a-soul-attach-to-the-body)

Answer (score 0):

Soul consists of mind, intellect and resolves (impressions).

Mind consists of 7 good layers and 7 bad layers. Humans who destroy the 7 bad layers using their intellect will succeed in life.

7 good layers are love, purity, knowledge, happiness, bliss, power, peace.
7 bad layers are lust, anger, greed, attachment, ego, hatred, jealousy.

https://youtu.be/BjteGz195iU

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).