# How to keep Pancha Kosha in Good state possible?

Tags: body

Are there any exercise, or anything to do, So I can keep Pancha Kosha in Good state possible..

Like Im guessing that for a Good

Annamaya Kosha - Asana, Good food Diet..

Pranamaya Kosha - Pranayama,

Manomaya Kosha - ??

Please write If there are anything else..

Comment: you are confusing pranamayakosa with prana. The pranamayakosa is a sheath, you cannot do an exercise for it, or physical pranayama. See here - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6758/where-does-a-soul-attach-to-the-body

Comment: Exercise or Practice, this site says Pranayama Practice for Pranamaya Kosha https://www.verywellfit.com/what-are-the-five-koshas-3566775