# Can physical injuries of past life be transferred to the new life?

Tags: rebirth

If someone dies due to physical injuries, will his injury be transferred to the new body (after reincarnation)?

And can one remember his past life without doing meditation or sadhana?

Comment: Physical injuries are part of the gross body is only the outer sheath. The outer sheath does not survive. Karma survives. Whether or not the karma that caused the physical injury manifests in an new birth depends upon whether the karma that caused it in the first place continues. See here - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6758/where-does-a-soul-attach-to-the-body

Comment: The answer, as one ought to know  just by reflecting on it, is no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are deeply interested in the subject, try reading the book - '[Where Reincarnation and Biology Intersect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_Reincarnation_and_Biology_Intersect)' by Ian Stevenson. There is a separate chapter dedicated to birthmarks which have been transferred to the reincarnated person. It is named, chapter 6 - Birthmarks Corresponding to Wounds Verified by Medical Records
Ian Stevenson was a research psychiatrist, who has taken much pains to research on the subject of reincarnation, proceeding by the scientific method. I.e., he like a sceptic, assumes that every such case is fraud, makes inventories of various items recognized by reborn people, conducts detailed investigations and enquiries, interviews the subjects himself, notes whether they make any contradictory statements, investigates any profit/popularity motive of the subject or his/her family, then records his case only when all of the criteria is passed and it is proved beyond doubt that there is no case of fraud/malafide. In the books, you can find details of the case, which are really detailed, for example the author goes on to find both the families castes, where they travelled, who they talked to, etc. to find out whether they ever met before/ could have planned it in a setup.
His book 'Twenty Cases Suggestive of Reincarnation' contains many such cases from India and Sri Lanka where the person, before dying has a serious injury, and in his next birth has a birthmark corresponding to the injured part in the body of the previous life.
Additionally [this](https://www.reincarnationresearch.com/past-life-story-of-james-huston-jr-james-leininger/) case might interest you, as the subject here investigated is an American fighter pilot, who remembered dying in the aircraft in a war in Japan.During his death, he couldn't get out of the cockpit, and remembered (in his reincarnated life) his legs going numb. In his reincarnated life, he had birth marks near his thighs/genital area. This shows some kind of a continuance of injury from the past life. [Here's](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1550830716000331) the corresponding research paper about of the same. It can be downloaded if you belong to any recognized university that has a tie-up with science direct. 

I deliberately present this case here as the subject's family happens to be Christian, who deny reincarnation due to faith. This shows that reincarnation is a purely objective phenomenon, which can be traced empirically, and has nothing to do with a person's beliefs. If you are interested in non-Indian cases of reincarnation type, you might want to look at the works of [Jim Tucker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_B._Tucker), who was the student of Ian Stevenson and specialized in cases of Western type. (USA, Europe) In this too, you can find cases of the injury type, subjects who had the birthmark corresponding to the injured area/part.
So, to answer your question, empirically, cases have been found which had the birthmarks corresponding to injury in the previous life. Generally, these cases pertain to birthmarks in the exact spot. For example, a person shot near his ear, can have a birthmark near his ear. However, this only indicates the possibility, and it is not necessary that a person who is reincarnated will have the birthmarks.
Note: The books of Ian Stevenson are deeply technical in nature and might not interest you if you are a layman looking for a casual light reading. Here's a [book](https://www.amazon.in/Life-Before-Childrens-Memories-Previous/dp/031237674X), if you are interested in a light read on reincarnation.
Now, I answer the second part of your question about reincarnation and sadhana. Sadhana is not done in order to remember past lives. It is done, so that you don't die after the shock your brain receives after remembering your past lives, according to Sadhguru. Due, to this, you will find in the books of Ian Stevenson, that the parents of the re-born child try to force him to forget about his/her previous life/lives. It is a long held belief in the Hindu society, that children who remember their previous lives do not live long. Stevenson also mentions this to be the reason for parents trying to make children forget their past lives. Sadhguru, in his book, [Death](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/50273386-death-an-inside-story) rationalizes this by explaining that recollecting the previous life has a huge impact on the mind of the person. If the person is not mature enough, he might be stuck between both his lives replaying the incidents from his past life, and connecting with the past identities. This causes the mind to be overburdened, as the mind is only designed to handle one identity in a lifetime. A person undergoing sadhana attains a certain maturity and non-attachment with his life, which enables him to handle previous life also, without getting entangled in memories and getting emotional. Thus, it is said that a guru can make anyone remember his past life, but does not do so, because of a responsibility towards life. It can be done for anyone, but if the person has not developed the maturity, it might lead to his death in days, if not instants.

Comment: Was just about to cite his work.

Comment: @Ikshvaku There you go. Hope you like it.

Comment: But can you provide some verse from vedas and upanishades that support your answer.