# Reincarnation and Atma

Tags: brahman

Atma or Brahman is considered as not having any properties(Nirguna). Then why the karma that lead to reincarnation attaches to it? Is Pind-deha has any connection with this?

Comment: Where did you read that anything can be attached to the *aatman*? Karmas are attached to and fruits experienced by the outer layers not the "true-Self".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where does a Soul attach to the Body?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6758/where-does-a-soul-attach-to-the-body)

Comment: Nirguna Brahman is without properties. Karams are attached within subtle body/Atman. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Bodies_Doctrine Reincarnation is of subtle body/Atman that has desires and effects of past Karmas(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanchita_karma) and its like a pen drive and can load in a new hardware called body with rebirth and even roam freely like ghost,spirit based on good or bad Karmas.

Answer (score -1):

It's due to string theory, everything is frequency after the smallest matter partical atom , quarks.
So the smallest known thing in any object will be a form of frequency only, that's the reason this frequency resonance according to act (karma) and indirectly karma effect you me mostly.
But some time you can also see the instant karma as well.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to HSE. Answers here must be backed with proper sources and citations. Please cite some authoritative scriptural sources. Also, We don't allow "Scientific-Speculations" on this site. Kindly have a look at [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions). Further, you may wanna go through [How does a new user get started on Hinduism SE?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se), to get familiar with our site.