# Anandamaya kosha versus karana shareera

Tags: vedanta, advaita

In advaita vedanta, they describe the body as being composed of 5 koshas :-
Annamaya, Pranamaya , Manomaya , vigyanamaya, and Anandamaya

There is another division into:-
Sthula shareera, Sukshma shareera, and Kaarana Shreera

Here it seems sthula shareera is same as annamaya kosha,
Sukshma shareera can be said to comprise of Pranamaya, Manomaya and Vigyanamaya koshas together.

But then is it right to also say that anandamaya kosha is same as kaarana shareera?

It seems confusing since anandamaya kosha is supposed to comprise of bliss. Whereas Kaarana shareera is the ignorance in deep sleep.

Although there is bliss in deep sleep as well but it seems bliss should be much more than that.

Comment: There is a school of thought in advaita that considers ignorance to exist in causal state in deep sleep. That a person "experiences" bliss in the state of deep sleep is well-accepted. So, there is bliss in deep sleep, but deep sleep is also a state where ignorance is present, but it is not showing any effects, so the ignorance is in causal state.

Comment: Bliss in reality is the state of Self/Atman, not in senses, temporary object of Maya for example only an alive person can enjoy food, watch tv, etc., not dead person who is missing basic Atman/Purusha required for enjoyment from inert material things of Prakriti. Deep Sleep is a form of natural involuntary Samadhi for all but broken by morning Sun for common beings, yogis who meditate can control the state of long deep sleep/Samadhi voluntary and taking bliss and revelations/wisdom from that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where does a Soul attach to the Body?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6758/where-does-a-soul-attach-to-the-body)

Comment: No the above does not compare anandamay kosha and kaarana shareera specifically.