# Does Vedanta believe that the intellect is material?

Tags: philosophy, vedanta, body, shad-darshana, buddhi

I read someone say that the Vedantins believe that the intellect is material. Is this true?

I really hope that this isn't true, because the intellect is obviously immaterial. Because the intellect deals with abstract, immaterial concepts, such as numbers.

If we make the error of saying that the intellect is material, then we are making the same error that the materialists make.

If the Vedantins believe that the intellect is material, then are there any other schools of thought that believe that intellect is immaterial?

Comment: A processor is one that has got all the intelligence , to run a PC or a mobile phone.In this case, Do you think it is a non-material ,or a material (an integrated elecronic circuit) ?

Comment: No, because processors don't have intellect. They can't think with abstractions.

Comment: By abstraction , do you mean perception, inference , decision making , synthesizing etc ? In my understanding, vedanta does not say , Intellect functions on its own.Only upon superimposition by Atman which is the only the non-material, the Intellect manifests and functions, otherwise it is defunct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where does a Soul attach to the Body?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6758/where-does-a-soul-attach-to-the-body)

Comment: the intellect is part of the mind, your 'ego', which is destroyed with the destruction of the body.

Comment: @TerjijKassal Intellect(buddhi) is considered by Vedānta to be beyond the five subtle and gross elements, as is the case in Sāṅkhya too, so it's not material exactly. The only Indian philosophical systems which considers intellect and consciousness to be confined to the body and hence products of matter are Cārvāka and Lokāyata

Comment: @Bingming OK I see